# XML will not load when called and undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

The error I get is

> Members.html:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: loadXMLDoc is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

And this is my HTML:

```
<p><button onclick="loadXMLDoc()"> Load Table </button></p> //this is where it is pointing at

<table id = "members" border= "1">
<tr><th colspan="3">Informatics Club Membership</colspan></th></tr>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Interests</th></tr>
</table>

<script>
    function loadXMLDoc(){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                myFunction(this);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "Members.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    
    function myFunction(xml){
        var x, i, xmlDoc, table;
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        table = "<tr><th colspan="0">Informatics Club Membership</colspan></th></tr><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Interests</th></tr>";
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("members");
        
        for(i= 0; i < x.length; i++){
            table += "<tr><td>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" + 
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("Email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" + 
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("Interests")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>";
        }
        document.getElementById("members").innerHTML = table;
    }   
</script>
```

Along with this code, I am not getting it to load my `members.xml` file, even when I am calling it with

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Members.xml", true);
```

I am a beginner so take it easy on me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in `myFunction`, the `colspan` attribute is not properly escaped which causes the contents of your script tag to be trashed. If you put the functions in their own tags only `myFunction` will not be defined.

```
table = "<tr><th colspan=\"0\">Informatics Club Membership</colspan></th></tr><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Interests</th></tr>";
```